# Design C++ DSL for notating and transferring trees

Tags: c++, templates, dsl, api-design, notation

#### In short

I am trying to design a nicer C++ interface for a C library that sends tree-like expressions through a communication channel (à la iostreams vs stdio). I am not sure if it is possible at all to design a DSL within C++ for notating these trees *while avoiding runtime overhead*, and if yes, how.

#### Simplified explanation of the C library

There is a C library which can send "expressions" through a communication channel.  An "expression" here means a tree structure that can be conveniently notated in a manner similar to function calls.

For example,

```
f(1, 2, g(3), "foo")
```

denotes this tree:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<sup>Some of you may recognize [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSPutFunction.html) at this point, but I decided to leave that out as it is irrelevant to the question.</sup>

We refer to `f` as *head* and `1`, `2`, `g(3)` as *arguments*.

To send this expression, we would write the following:

```c
putHead("f" /* name */, 3 /* argument count */);
  putInteger(1);
  putInteger(2);
  putHead("g" /* name */, 1 /* argument count */);
    putInteger(3);
  putString("foo");
```

#### Question

Is it possible to design a more convenient C++ API for this with the following features?

1. More concise to write (think `iostreams` vs `stdio`)
2. Does away with the need to explicitly specify the argument count for each head; instead uses a convenient notation (analogous to `f(1,2,g(3))` from above) from which it infers the argument count automatically
3. Achieves (2) without runtime overhead (i.e. infer argument count at compile time)
4. Must use the above described C interface behind the scenes

I can do (1) with a streams-like interface (i.e. no need to explicitly specify the type of Integer, String, etc. of each argument).  I can do (2) in a way that involves extra runtime computation.  But I do not know if (2)/(3) *together* are possible given the features of C++.   Ultimately I would like to have a convenient notation for these expressions within C++ itself.

**So is it possible to design a DSL within C++ for this *while avoiding all runtime overhead*?  If yes, how?  I am not necessarily looking for a full solution with code as the answer, just some pointers to get started, or a summary of an approach that would likely work.**

Comment: "expression templates" could be helpful

Comment: Downvoters: please add a comment, and give me a chance to address any problems.

Comment: Here are [three attempts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db8d49a5a958ccf7) to get close to the syntax you want. All three just stuff the arguments into a tuple, but it should be possible to recurse through those and make the appropriate C API calls.

Comment: @melak47 Thank you so much for the hints.  I was swamped with work so I couldn't give this enough time yet, but I wanted to give you a sign that I did look at your code and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to represent a tree in C++.  The implementation for some of these (#1, #2) would involve building an intermediate structure, and then calling the C functions at the end.  Others (#5, #6) could call the C functions as you go, because the number of children of any node is known at compile-time.

1) Using a fluent interface and overloading:

```
Tree()
  .head("f")
    .put(1)
    .put(2)
    .head("g")
      .put(3)
      .end()
    .put("foo")
    .end();
```

2) Or alternatively, without calls to end():

```
head("f")
  .put(1)
  .put(2)
  .put(head("g")
    .put(3))
  .put("foo");
```

3) Using operator<<:

```
Tree("f")
  << 1
  << 2
  << (Tree("g") << 3)
  << "foo";
```

4) Using operator():

```
Tree("f")
  (1)
  (2)
  (Tree("g")(3))
  ("foo")
```

5) Using std::initializer_list where Node is a type that is implicitly convertible from both int and std::string:

```
Tree { "f", {
  1,
  2,
  { "g", { 3 } }
  "foo",
} }
```

6) Using variadic templates:

```
head("f").put(
  1,
  2,
  head("g").put(3)
  "foo");
```